# JSON data not printing but prints on click (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null)

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, json

I'm trying to print one of my data strings in HTML paragraph to test if the data is working. However, when I try and getElementById I get the error above. Although when I use a button to call the function I have no issues in printing the data. I think this has something to do with the order the data is read in, but I'm not quite sure. The code I have used is as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
  </head>   
  <body>
     
      <p id="demo">  </p>
      
      <script type="text/javascript">
          //Stores data
          var Data = null;
          fetch('fetch.php')
          .then(data => data.json())
          .then(data => {
              //Set data
              Data = data;
              console.log(Data);
          });
          
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Data[1].name;
         function myFunction() {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Data[1].name;}
         
          
</script>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have any further questions please ask as I was struggling how to word this. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Could you share the .php file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `fetch` performs its tasks asynchronously and you are trying to access `Data` before its value is available.

Please try the following code.

I recommend you to read more about JS Promises and asynchronous code execution. However, if you have any doubt, please let me know.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id='demo'>  </p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let Data = null;
    let myFunction = function () {
        console.log('DATA IS NOT READY YET.');
    };
    
    fetch('fetch.php')
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
            myFunction = function () {
                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = data[1].name;
            };
        });
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```